# Is there a Turkish checkers game for Ubuntu desktop?If not, can it be implemented?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

Straight working checkers is better than cross working checkers.Can it be implemented?

Comment: Ubuntu developers won't write software for you. If you discover or create linux-compatible software that you want to see in Ubuntu, you must *package* it for Debian. It will sync into Ubuntu after it's accepted into Debian. Start your packaging journey at http://mentors.debian.net. Alternately, you can create a snap of the software (http://snapcraft.io)

Answer (score 0):

You can play Dama (turkish checkers) with [hcheckers](https://github.com/portnov/hcheckers), both against a human opponent and against the computer.

This software is written in a client server architecture, i.e., it comes in two binaries: a server and a client. If you just want to play checkers on your desktop computer, you need to start a local server program first, and then start the client program.

While the developer does provide Ubuntu packages for hcheckers 0.1 (one for the server and one for the client), unfortunately, this version is too old and does not contain the turkish variant yet (only the english and russian variants and some others). So you need to build the package from the sources yourself. You can either build Ubuntu packages or docker containers. The README of hcheckers describes how to do this. Or, you could open a ticket on GitHub and kindly ask the developer to release a new version.